# Re-fetching resolved data for child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-resolver

I have a parent component that loads child components conditionally. One of them being:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="someCondition">
    <app-some-child></app-some-child>
</ng-container>
```

There are no child routes for the parent component. The route has a resolver to which `app-some-child` subscribes to:

```
this._activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ clientData }) => {
  // Client data came from a server
});
```

The child component `app-some-child` is used to create the client data:

```
this.clientService.create(client).subscribe(res => {
  // Client created
});
```

**The problem**

When I navigate back and forth between child components, the resolver is obviously "not designed" to be called again in this way. So, after creating a client, what is the best approach to use in order to keep the client data when initializing `app-some-child` again but still using the resolver?

**"Dirty" solutions:**

1. I could re-subscribe to getting the client from server on `app-child-component` but then I'm dealing with duplicate subscriptions.
2. I can use a singleton to keep the client in memory after creating it and subscribe to it.